# Como retornar via PHP várias mensagens JSON, sendo que cada uma é disparada em momentos diferentes?

Tags: php, json, ajax

Estou construindo um sistema e em certa etapa ele salva 3 conjuntos de informações preenchidas no formulário pelo operador do sistema:

- Conjunto 1: informações do aluno;
- Conjunto 2: informações do fiador do aluno;
- Conjunto 3: informações sobre a matricula do aluno.

Estou fazendo as requisições ao código que salva as informações via `AJAX` (usando `jQuery`), e no lado servidor o script `PHP` faz algumas verificações e retorna algumas mensagens.

Por exemplo, o sistema verifica a existência do registro do aluno e avisa o operador, depois verifica e pode alertar que o CPF do fiador é inválido (caso passe da validação js).

O que acontece é que como são duas séries de mensagens ele faz isso:

Resposta Ajax dando erro 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No código PHP estou fazendo assim:

Avisos para o conjunto 1 de informações

```php
// encontrou Registros do Aluno 
if($busca_aluno['sys'] === '002' && $aguardando_usuario === false){ 
$retorna['msg'] = 'Este Aluno foi reconhecido pelo sistema';

//verifica status da matrícula do aluno
if($busca_aluno['situacao_pessoa'] === 1){ //ativa, identifica rematrícula

    $operacao_aluno = 'rematricula'; //updt
    $retorna['msg'] .= '<p>A matricula do Aluno esta ativa e sera realizada a <strong>REMATRICULA</strong> dele. Aguarde...</p>';

}elseif($busca_aluno['situacao_pessoa'] === 0){ //inativa, identifica que o aluno passou um certo período sem se matricular

    $operacao_aluno = 'matricula'; //insert
    $retorna['msg'] .= '<p>A matricula do aluno estava inativa, ele sera matriculado normalmente.</p>';

}else{ // situação desconhecida

    $operacao_aluno = 'matricula'; //insert
    $retorna['msg'] .= "<p>O codigo retornado pelo sistema para a situacao do aluno, e um codigo invalido de acordo com as diretrizes.</p>";
    $retorna['msg'] .= "<p><strong>Informe a matrícula do aluno ao suporte. O cadastro do aluno sera continuado como MATRICULA.</strong></p>";

}

// adiciona os dados de código do sistema ao array de mensagem
$retorna = array_merge($busca_aluno, $retorna); 
echo json_encode($retorna); // aviso na tela
}
```

A estrutura de avisos dos outros conjuntos seguem a mesma estrutura, os avisos surgem um atrás do outro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você usa três instruções para retornar o JSON:

```php
echo json_encode($retorna1);
echo json_encode($retorna2);
echo json_encode($retorna3);
```

Cada `json_encode` está gerando um array associativo (`{ ... }`) e, ao concatenar as três respostas, você tem um JSON mal formado. Como você quer retornar três coisas, você deve retornar uma lista, que em JSON é representada por `[ ... ]`, com elementos separados por vírgulas.

A solução é, então, criar um array para servir de lista, adicionar cada resposta e no final retornar o `json_encode` dessa lista:

```php
$lista_retorna = array();
$lista_retorna[] = $retorna1;
$lista_retorna[] = $retorna2;
$lista_retorna[] = $retorna3;

echo json_encode($lista_retorna);
```

O JSON resultado será válido, no formato `[{...}, {...}, {...}]`, onde cada `{...}` é uma resposta.

Comment: Excelente! não tinha pensado nisso.
A minha estrutura de avisos tem apresentado este incômodo principalmente porque o processamento não é demorado, e o tempo que cada mensagem aparece na tela do usuário provavelmente não é o suficiente. Acho que vou extinguir as mensagens e mostrar somente as realmente necessárias. A menos que surja alguma arquitetura de interação com o usuário mais interessante.